# Searching mismatched changes between Perforce branches

Tags: perforce

There are four branches in Perforce depot: B1, B2, B3 and B4.
Let's think B1 as main (core, trunk).
B2 and B3 could contain changes which **must** be included into B1 but missed by some reasons.
B4 is target branch which is already created from B1 but because of missed B2 and B3 changes in B1 is not full.
The goal is to build **list of files** (not make merge!) which were not propagated from B2 and B3 to B1 (one list) and which were not propagated from B1 to B4

Comment: It seems like `p4 integrate -n` should be the foundation of your approach.

Comment: @BryanPendleton: tried and failed to understand - how could `p4 integrate -n` useful for this issue. It makes integration but does not prepare any lists of files. Could you please be more detailed?

Comment: A more detailed example added as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example. It's small, but hopefully it's enough to give you the idea.

```
C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>mkdir B1

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>cd B1

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client\B1>vim f1 f2

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client\B1>p4 add f1 f2
//depot/B1/f1#1 - opened for add
//depot/B1/f2#1 - opened for add

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client\B1>p4 submit -d add_B1
Submitting change 15.
Locking 2 files ...
add //depot/B1/f1#1
add //depot/B1/f2#1
Change 15 submitted.

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client\B1>p4 populate //depot/B1/... //depot/B2/...
2 files branched (change 16).

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client\B1>p4 populate //depot/B1/... //depot/B3/...
2 files branched (change 17).

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client\B1>p4 edit B1/f1
B1/f1 - file(s) not on client.

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client\B1>p4 sync
//depot/B2/f1#1 - added as c:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client\B2\f1
//depot/B2/f2#1 - added as c:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client\B2\f2
//depot/B3/f1#1 - added as c:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client\B3\f1
//depot/B3/f2#1 - added as c:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client\B3\f2

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client\B1>cd ..\

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 edit B2\f1
//depot/B2/f1#1 - opened for edit

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>vim B2\f1

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 submit -d add_to_B2
Submitting change 18.
Locking 1 files ...
edit //depot/B2/f1#2
Change 18 submitted.

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 edit B3/f2
//depot/B3/f2#1 - opened for edit

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>vim B3\f2

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 submit -d insert_to_B3
Submitting change 19.
Locking 1 files ...
edit //depot/B3/f2#2
Change 19 submitted.

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 populate //depot/B1/... //depot/B4/...
2 files branched (change 20).

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 integrate -n //depot/B2/... //depot/B1/...
//depot/B1/f1#1 - integrate from //depot/B2/f1#2

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 integrate -n //depot/B3/... //depot/B1/...
//depot/B1/f2#1 - integrate from //depot/B3/f2#2

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 integrate -n //depot/B2/... //depot/B4/...
//depot/B4/f1#1 - sync/integrate from //depot/B2/f1#2

C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 integrate -n //depot/B3/... //depot/B4/...
//depot/B4/f2#1 - sync/integrate from //depot/B3/f2#2
```

Comment: BTW, in case when f1 was integrated from B1 to B2 and modified in B1 then `p4 integrate -n //depot//B2/... //depot/B1/...` shows that f1 must be integrated to B1 but actually - no, because it is come from B1 immediately. Is there any way to recognize such situations?